# A program to update the public IP address of a network/ computer to a website

Tags: macos, ip

Sorry if this is not really relevant to stack overflow but I'm sure someone will know the answer.

I have a Mac at home and want the IP address of that network to be sent to a page on my website.

I have port forwarded a program on my Mac and want to access it when I am out and about. I've tried dynamic DNS and have had no luck due to my routers lack of editable settings.

I would really appreciate it if someone knew of a way that I could find out the public IP address of my home network remotely by having it updating on my website, or if this is not possible a service which offers this ability.

Obviously it would be great if this was a free service/ program.

Thanks in advance,

Ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a bash script that sends to your website. you must be something know about API for your website.

for try this also http://www.noip.com/download?page=mac

Comment: Thanks for your answer, had a play with no-ip but had no success but i will try again!

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://noip.com. 
I think they have a mac tool to do this.